# How to split SQL script by GO in SMO from C#

Tags: c#, smo

I know, SMO can execute the script with `GO` statements, but in this way it doesn't return the affected rows separately for each contained batch.
To retreive affected rows separately, I have to call `server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery()` with `StringCollection` parameter.
I don't want to use `ScriptDom`, it is very complex. I don't want to use Regex split also, it wouldn't produce exact result.

Is there any simple method in Microsoft SMO to split SQL script file by `GO` statement into a `StringCollection`?

Comment: What would not be "exact" about doing a regex split on `@"^\s*GO\s*\r\n"`? Why would you need to involve SMO-specific classes?

Comment: I should like to work it exactly like SQL Server Management Studio. I think, SMO fulfills this requirement..

Comment: SMO uses Entity which is a different driver from SQLClient.  The SMO is linq and you should be able to use .CopyToDataTable() method to get the rows.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. Where can I use .CopyToDataTable() ?

Comment: `ExecuteBatch.GetStatements()` performs the parsing for `ExecuteNonQuery`. Use at your own risk -- though the type is public and present in API lists (without any actual explicit documentation), there's probably a good reason why the SMO code actually invokes it through reflection rather than a direct reference, so it might not exactly be stable. I'm pretty sure this *doesn't* work "exactly like SQL Server Management Studio" since I don't believe it supports the `GO  <number>` syntax SSMS does, but I haven't tested. SSMS, SMO and `sqlcmd` probably all implement their own logic.

Comment: This is the solution, this is what I have been searching for! I have tested, it works well. It executes GO n syntax also. I used through direct reference. 
I will proceed with tests.